# Weird syntax error for just comment lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I am getting some really weird syntax errors [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier] for seemingly normal code.

Getting an error if I write anything after the 1st line in the else block..

```
if (classlist.length == 0) {    
        lastClickCatID = -1;
}
else {
    lastClickCatID = +classlist.value.split('-')[1];
    // **Getting error if I write anything here, even for comments like this**
}
```

Getting the error if I just use two words in the comment (with a space between them). And of course getting error for any JS statements, even basic console logs.

Also, getting an error for a console.log line in the following code which has been commented out (the 4th line: console.log-"UNDO"):

```
// Push this data into the undo array
undo.push([lastClickDivID, lastClickCol, lastClickRow, lastClickCatID, nextClickCatID]);

//console.log("UNDO", undo[0][0], undo[0][1], undo[0][2], undo[0][3], undo[0][4]); // *Getting error if I include this line*
console.log(undo.pop());
```

Getting an error with or without the comment tag. But if I remove the entire line, it works fine.

I have another line:

```
nextClickCatID = +id2;
```

Again getting errors for doing a console.log of the variable. But it works fine if I remove the '+' and just use next 'nextClickCatID = id2; '.

Also getting many other weird errors like that within this function (it will get too long if I include them). Any idea why I am getting errors like these for seemingly normal code?

Comment: Could you show us a more complete example of your code - or ideally a working example of the error in a snippet in your question

Comment: why do you have a + sign infront of the variables?

Comment: @N. Ivanov - The +sign parses them into int. I am getting some errors even if I remove it completely, or use parseInt.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sure, I will upload a code snippet in the comment section here with more details in 2-mins..

Comment: @N.Ivanov https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I was not aware of this functionality

Comment: Please don't post code (or other important or relevant information) as comments. Edit your question to include that instead.

Comment: I think there is an error here - lastClickCatID = +classlist.value.split('-')[1];  It should be - lastClickCatID =+ classlist.value.split('-')[1];  There must not be ant space between = and +.

Comment: @T.Shah - ok I tried it, but it still gives the same errors. It strangely worked when I removed space between parentheses and the curly brackets in  jquery document ready function (see my answer below)

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting? Are you building these with webpack? Are you using browserify? JSLint, ESLint? Anything?

Comment: @DDRamone - I was only getting a syntax error at the jquery 'document ready function' line. And the entire page wasn't loading. I assumed error must be somewhere higher up in the code. Am using Chrome DevTools

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. It strangely worked when I removed the space between the () and the curly brackets in the jquery document ready function. Changed from...

```
$(function() {
```

to:

```
$(function(){   // with no space between the  parentheses and the curly brackets
```

I want to add that - it was working fine before with the same structure (with space in between brackets) all this while. But suddenly decided to give an error today in a particular function. If somebody can clarify why this happened, it will still be very relevant.